# How to convert "unsigned long long int" into Java?

Tags: java, c

Here is a code written in C. It receives an integer as command line argument, and calcurate recurrence relation.

I would like to convert this code into Java, but not sure how to rewrite the following part. Does anyone know how can I write it by Java?

> unsigned long long int gn[3]={0,0,1}, tmp;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned long long int gn[3]={0,0,1}, tmp;
    int i, j;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    for(i=3; i<=n; i++){
        tmp = 0;
        for(j=0; j<3; j++){
            tmp += gn[j];
        }
        gn[0] = gn[1];
        gn[1] = gn[2];
        gn[2] = tmp;
    }
    if(n<2){
        printf("%ld\n",gn[n]);
    }else{
        printf("%llu\n",gn[2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Result

Input:   1,
Output:  0

Input: 5,
Output:  4

Input: 10,
Output:  81

Input: 30,
Output:  15902591

Comment: Already two good answers below, but relevant info: the data type `unsigned long long int` is a 64-bit value ([source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-value-of-unsigned-long-long-int-in-c/).

Comment: Actually, it is *at least* a 64-bit value ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types))   Which renders one of the answers *technically* incorrect.  (But AFAIK, there are no mainstream C++ implementations where there the `long long int` types are more than 64 bits wide.)

Comment: Oh nice, yeah if `unsigned long long int` can be more than 64-bit, using Long definitely wouldn't work.

Comment: (Though GCC C++ supports `__int128` types on hardware with 128 bit integer support.  So it is not beyond the bounds of possibility that they might optionally equate those with `long long int`.)

Comment: The lesson here is that when you are writing C++ code and you need to be precise about data type ranges, you need to write your code *carefully* if you want it to be portable.   By contrast, in Java the ranges are specified by the language rather than the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks trivial to rewrite with `BigInteger`. Note that `argv[0]` in C++ is the program name. Java does not follow that convention. So it might look something like,

```
BigInteger[] gn = { BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE };
int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
    BigInteger tmp = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        tmp = tmp.add(gn[j]);
    }
    gn[0] = gn[1];
    gn[1] = gn[2];
    gn[2] = tmp;
}
System.out.println(gn[Math.min(n, 2)]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting Java 8, there is support for unsigned long (unsigned 64 bits). The way you can use it is:

`Long l1 = Long.parseUnsignedLong("17916881237904312345");`

To print it, you can not simply print l1, but you have to first:

`String l1Str = Long.toUnsignedString(l1)`

Then
`System.out.println(l1Str);`

If you are using Java version less than Java 8 then you should use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: This is a good answer, and does address the specific question of handling unsigned 64-bit numbers, but using BigInteger is safer – it doesn't allow incorrectly treating the Long as a signed value. That is, this approach works if caller knows to use `Long.toUnsignedString()`, but doesn't work if caller (or anyone who encounters the value) doesn't handle it propertly.

Comment: Oh, update: this is less correct, as Stephen C commented, `unsigned long long int` is [_at least_ 64 bits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) – so it could be greater than 64, which would exceed [java.lang.Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html).